# How call a custom url protocol in C#?

Tags: c#, custom-protocol

I try to call a custom protocol app from my API in C#.

my custom protocol is installed and I can call it in my browser with "my-app://myParams" URI, 
but I don't know how call a custom URL with webrequest. I tried to add a new object implementing IWebRequestCreate and called-it but I have  stackoverflow error.

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("my-app", new MyCustomWebRequestCreator());
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("my-app:");

internal class CustomWebRequestCreator : IWebRequestCreate
{
    WebRequest IWebRequestCreate.Create(Uri uri)
    {
        return WebRequest.Create(uri); // what can I do here ?
    }
}
```

with the last code I have a stackoverflow exception  on my WebRequest.Create(uri) method, but I don't know what to do in this method.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `I have a stackoverflow exception` Please show us the stack.

Comment: A [mcve] would be great too,

Comment: Doesn't Webrequest.Create call prefix creator inside? I would expect that when you register your prefix it means that your handler will be called, and inside your handler you call Webrequest.Create which calls your handler etc.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/Net/WebRequest.cs,05d0bbbd85e185ee,references it's not very readable from the phone, however I think there is the logic which looks for prefix handler inside Create method.

Comment: Have you ever got this working?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.iwebrequestcreate.create?view=netframework-4.8) says:

> The Create method must return an initialized instance of the WebRequest descendant that is capable of performing a standard request/response transaction for the protocol without needing any protocol-specific fields modified.

So first you need to create a WebRequest descendant:

```
class AWebRequestDescendant : WebRequest
{
   ...
}
```

Then initialize and return it

```
WebRequest IWebRequestCreate.Create(Uri uri)
{
    return new AWebRequestDescendant();
}
```